# CodeIgniter - Doctrine - DateDiff

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine, datediff

I have been meaning to use the MySQL DATEDIFF function but I have never been successful.

I followed the tutorial here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

I have set the configuration properly

```
$config = new Configuration;
$config->addCustomStringFunction('DATEDIFF', 'Project\ORM\MySql\DateDiff');
```

I also placed the file to the correct location.

Currently, the path for my under libraries is:

```
libraries
--Doctrine
--Project
----ORM
------MySql
---------DateDiff.php
--Doctrine.php
```

And my code for DateDiff.php is:

```
class DateDiff extends FunctionNode
{
// (1)
public $firstDateExpression = null;
public $secondDateExpression = null;

public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
{
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER); // (2)
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS); // (3)
    $this->firstDateExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary(); // (4)
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA); // (5)
    $this->secondDateExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary(); // (6)
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS); // (3)
}

public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    return 'DATEDIFF(' .
        $this->firstDateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
        $this->secondDateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
    ')'; // (7)
}
}
```

And this is how I attempt to catch it:

```
$this->doctrine->em->
createQuery('SELECT a FROM models\user_table a 
WHERE a.user_id = '.$user_id.' 
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.created_at) < 1')
->getResult();
```

I basically just copied over what was written in the cookbook.

However, I can't get it to work as my application fails to display any output. No errors. It just stops there.

Anybody has any idea where the issue might be? Is it a pathing issue?  Or am I not calling it correctly?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to get the final sql with `->getSql()` and test it in your DB console